# Twitter bootstrap .on calls

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Just a small question. If you trigger the following code from multiple locations, does the latter one replace the function of the previous one or does it append?

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

For example when you do something like

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  // do something…
})
//---
//and then using the modal id
//---
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

Comment: Why not try it before asking? seems like something easy enough to test.

Comment: @KevinB For the small details in the answers that might show up. For example, even after a test, my attention would never go to the "first in first out" as you explain below.

Comment: It's also noted in the api documentation. http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: eh, i guess the first-in-first-out portion was left off in the .on documentation. It's in .bind documentation: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple calls to .on on the same element adds new events on top of the previous ones. They will get executed first in first out.